# Como usar "and" em seletores CSS3?

Tags: css, css3

Estou a tentar selecionar somente inputs cuja classe comece com "btn_" e que tenham também `type="button"`.

Exemplo:

```
input[type="button"] **&&** [class^="btn_"]
```

É possivel fazer isto?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim é possivel, é só juntar as duas condições.

```
input[type="button"][class^="btn_"] {
    height: 200px;
}
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/cj9jqofw/

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Funcionou perfeitamente.